# Apache server don't read updated files

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I am not sure of exact problem but suddenly Apache server on ubuntu 32bit VPS started causing problem. There is an opensource script installed on the server. 
I have made some changes to a PHP file and when I save the file I don't see the change on frontend at all. Even if I delete the file the system still run stable and the file can be accessed on frontend.

This is something strange.

Anyone out there who has fixed the similar problem before?

Thanks

P.S Tried rebooting server and apache itself

Comment: this problem can be caused by using some of php accelerators (APC for example), it caches file content until you restart apache, more information can be found here http://ua2.php.net/apc/

Comment: tried restarting apache and the whole server. Still not resolved.

Comment: another thought, it can be your browser cache, or some frontend server which caches response.

Comment: tried clearing browser cache as well neither I am using any CDN. :(
Its really hard to figure out.

Comment: If your site are using templates like smarty there may be cache directory, try delete it to refresh your site.

Comment: in this case can't help you, check everything few times: if it is right server, right virtual host, right path to script, no rewrite rules which points to another file etc.

Comment: It worked! You were right, it was memcached server. I tried flushing contenet, restarrted the memcached server, and it works now.

Thanks Mate :)